# Пунктуационные знаки

Tags: пунктуация

"Абсолютно неинформативной, если не сказать бессодержательной, представляется статья" — верно стоят пунктуационные знаки?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая после "бессодержательной" не нужна.

*Вопрос № 203869 

...
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Сочетания *чтобы не сказать, если не сказать* не являются вводными, они выступают в роли градационных союзов. Поэтому запятая ставится только с одной стороны - перед *если* (*чтобы*). 
...*
gramota.ru

Хотя тут действительно не совсем все однозначно. Можно ведь и как вводное воспринять, это от автора зависит. Ну коли уж авторитеты рекомендуют, спорить не буду.

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже больше нравится обособление этого оборота. Почему мы не можем рассматривать эту конструкцию как вставную? (Не вводную - тут действительно нет значения. присущего вводным словам и словосочетаниям - а именно как вставную)

Comment: А что за значение такое, должное быть присущим вводным словам?  

Вот с gramota.ru:
*Вводные слова – это слова, формально не связанные с членами предложения, не являющиеся членами предложения и выражающие отношение к сообщаемому или его характеристику. С грамматической точки зрения вводные слова представлены различными глагольными формами (личными формами, инфинитивами, деепричастиями), существительными и местоимениями (с предлогами и без предлогов), наречиями, именными и глагольными фразеологизмами. *
Пока ничего неподходящего.

Comment: Более того:
*Первая трудность заключается в том, что среди вводных слов и сочетаний очень мало таких, которые употребляются только как вводные и, следовательно, всегда обособляются (напр., во-первых, по-моему, с позволения сказать)*.  
Чем, простите, "что бы не сказать" отличается от "с позволения сказать"?  
Так что пока меня в невозможности считать вводным не убедили.